# Access KeychainAccess methods from Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, swift, keychain

I have an Objective-C project and this project uses KeychainAccess (Swift project) on some of my Swift file.  However, I do have the need to access KeychainAccess on some of my Objective-C file as well.

I imported the following:

```
#import "MyProject-Swift.h"
@import KeychainAccess;
```

I can't seem to reference KeychainAccess classes besides: `KeychainAccessVersionNumber` and `KeychainAccessVersionString`

What do I need to do to use its classes?
Thanks

Comment: You sure about `@import`? I'm thinking `import KeychainAccess`?

Comment: KeychainAccess is a seperate framework. It's another project included in my workspace. According to Apple, I need to @import to include external framework.